# Spring: Injecting a Scala List

Tags: java, spring, scala

This can be done using a converter wrapper:

```scala
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object ListConverter {

  def toScalaList( jlist: java.util.List[AnyRef] ) = {
    jlist.toList
  }
}
```

which uses a `implicit def asScalaBuffer` in `JavaConversions` to return a Scala List. Then I can make the list injectable as:

```xml
<bean id="someItems" class="my.package.ListConverter" factory-method="toScalaList">
    <constructor-arg type="java.util.List">
        <util:list>
            <ref bean="itemOne"/>
            <ref bean="itemTwo"/>
        </util:list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**I would like to find a cleaner way to do this**

I can't really use `JavaConversions` directly as a static factory call:

```xml
<bean id="someItems" class="scala.collection.JavaConversions" factory-method="asScalaBuffer">...</bean>
```

Since an `implicit def` is not really a static method in a Java universe.

*P.S. To get it out of the way.. I know there are a lot of annotation driven config lovers, but I am not one of them, and that is not a solution I am looking for: **I like my XML for Spring configs**, and **I like Spring to DI Scala***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert a `java.util.List` to a scala `List` you will have to provide your own conversion/factory method as no such method exists.

`JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer` could be referenced exactly as you did in your XML definition as the Scala compiler generates static forwarder methods to the `object` instance unless you tell it not to do so.
The problem here is actually actually that this method returns a `scala.collection.mutable.Buffer` which you still have to convert into a `List`.

An alternative is to accept an instance of `Seq[A]` to be injected. This would work as `Buffer[A]` extends `Seq[A]` - but you have to be aware that you are injecting a wrapper around the (possibly mutable) `java.util.List<A>` instance then.

Comment: yes, <bean id="someItems" class="scala.collection.JavaConversions" factory-method="asScalaBuffer"> does the trick, not sure why it was not compiling before, but then IntelliJ Scala plugin does it sometimes.. Good idea about using Seq[A] instead of List[A] => may not be really advocating strong collection type, but in my case, it does not really matter weather it is a List or a Seq. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ListConverter` was an `object` rather than a `class`, would not `toScalaList` be accepted as a static method ?

Comment: yep, that is also something I tried, which does work. It just does not feel clean to have a wrapper (ListConverter) around a wrapper (JavaConversions) to inject a List.

Comment: I edited the question to incorporate your suggestion, as the _question_ does look a lot cleaner with it, and voted you up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is that, behind the scenes, Spring is inherently untyped.  That list you're attempting to inject actually starts out as a `List<String>` before Spring determines the correct type of the target param/property.

In *some* cases, it can do this because the relevant type is retained in bytecode (even if it's erased on the JVM), this won't work in the case of injecting to generic methods.  In other cases, it can determine the type of a collection by inspecting elements. It *usually* gets this right, depending on how much polymorphism is involved.

Of course, all that logic is based entirely on `java.util.Collection` and subclasses, so Scala's collection types simply don't get to join the party.

You have three solutions here:

1. Learn to love annotation-driven injection.  You won't be bitten by the insidious weak-typing.
2. Create an overload of the setter method, or an auxiliary constructor that takes equivalent Java collection types.  Then use `collection.JavaConverters` to handle the conversion.  Spring is then happy because it's still within its Java-only comfort zone.
3. (my personal favourite) Stop using Spring

You're guaranteed to eventually run into problems with your converter, this will happen at around the time you discover the need to deal with the parity mismatch between boxed and unboxed primitives.